# An unhandled exception occurred: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match

Tags: angular, webpack

I am using angular version 12.

Related to some other problem that I have in my application

```
https://github.com/polkadot-js/extension/issues/621
```

i need to include some webpack configuration in my project

So for that reason i go in extra `extra-webpack.config` file and there i add the rules property

and now my file looks like this

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    /**
     * Remove all unused MomentJS locales
     * The problem is described in this article
     * https://medium.jonasbandi.net/angular-cli-and-moment-js-a-recipe-for-disaster-and-how-to-fix-it-163a79180173
     */
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[/\\]locale$/, /de|en|fr|it/),
    ],
    rules: [
        {
            include: /node_modules/,
            test: /\.mjs$/,
            type: 'javascript/auto'
        },
    ]
}
```

after that when i try to build my project i get error.

What is my mistake ? How can i add rule to my project ?

This is the full error that i am getting

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration has an unknown property 'rules'. These properties are valid:
   object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?, devServer?, devtool?, entry?, externals?, infrastructureLogging?, loader?, mode?, module?, name?, node?, optimization?, output?, parallelism?, performance?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, serve?, stats?, target?, watch?, watchOptions? }
   For typos: please correct them.
   For loader options: webpack >= v2.0.0 no longer allows custom properties in configuration.
     Loaders should be updated to allow passing options via loader options in module.rules.
     Until loaders are updated one can use the LoaderOptionsPlugin to pass these options to the loader:
     plugins: [
       new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
         // test: /\.xxx$/, // may apply this only for some modules
         options: {
           rules: …
         }
       })
     ]
```